# Opening code pane in full screen in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2017, editor, fullscreen

To toggle between full screen for a code pane docked within the Visual Studio's main window you can use `Shift` + `Alt` + `Enter` (ref: http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/).

However, if you have multiple monitors and have dragged a code pane to a different monitor, this does not work (despite ensuring that that is the active pane/window).  i.e. You still see this code pane's title bar, which takes up 2 lines for the window header, 1 line for the file tab, and another line for the navigation dropdowns.  e.g.

[image: Screenshot of VS2017 Code Pane Full Screen]

**Question:** Is there a way to hide / remove any of this, to maximise screen real estate for code?